# Exclude toString() from Lombok @Builder

Tags: java, lombok

The lombok `@Builder` creates a default `toString()` - I do not want this.

Does anyone know the best approach to exclude?

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help to know *why* you want to exclude the builder class's toString().

Anyway, according to the docs, you can supply a skeleton builder class yourself and implement toString() in it.

See https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder :

> Lombok will generate everything that you do not manually add

Comment: Thank you - I was aware of that - I was just hoping that there might some configuration key with the `@Builder` annotation. The _why_ is to avoid any prospect of sensitive data being inadvertently being put in the logs.